# Send data from android to mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I could really need some help to my project.

I have an android app, that scans for wireless networks. I want to upload this data to a mysql database.

Android have database class:

```
public class Database {

public static void putServerData(String building, String floor, String room, String address, String signal){
    String db_url = "http://**(IP ADDRESS)**/setdata.php";

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    InputStream is = null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> request = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    request.add(new BasicNameValuePair("building",building));
    request.add(new BasicNameValuePair("floor",floor));
    request.add(new BasicNameValuePair("room",room));
    request.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address",address));
    request.add(new BasicNameValuePair("signal",signal));


    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(db_url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(request));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){

    }

}
```

This is called by:

```
            try {
                Database.putServerData(building,floor, room, array1.get(1).toString(), array2.get(2).toString());                   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("test", "test");
            }
```

The server is a Win7 machine, with apache php and mysql

The setdata.php file:

```
   <?php
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass");
   if(!$con)
   {
 echo 'Not connected';
 echo ' - ';

  }else
  {
 echo 'Connection Established';
 echo ' - ';
 }

 $db = mysql_select_db("android");
 if(!$db)
 {
echo 'No database selected';
 }else
 {
echo 'Database selected';
 }



$building = $_POST['building'];
$floor = $_POST['floor'];
$room = $_POST['room'];
$ap_mac1 = $_POST['ap_mac1'];
$ap_strength1 = $_POST['ap_strength1'];
$ap_mac2 = $_POST['ap_mac2'];
$ap_strength2 = $_POST['ap_strength2'];
$ap_mac3 = $_POST['ap_mac3'];
$ap_strength3 = $_POST['ap_strength3'];
$ap_mac4 = $_POST['ap_mac4'];
$ap_strength4 = $_POST['ap_strength4'];
$ap_mac5 = $_POST['ap_mac5'];
$ap_strength5 = $_POST['ap_strength5'];

    echo ($_POST['building']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wifiscan VALUES($nextid, '$building','$floor','$room','$ap_mac1','$ap_strength1','$ap_mac2','$ap_strength2', '$ap_mac3', '$ap_strength3', '$ap_mac4', '$ap_strength4', '$ap_mac5', '$ap_strength5')");



mysql_close(); ?>
```

This is not working. Im not sure i select the database in the correct way, could that be the problem?

Maybe this isnt so clear and ill will explain it further if you want.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What is happening?

Comment: Ive tried to set some outputs in php file (see edited php code)

the output in the browser: Connection Established - Database selected

But the code echo ($_POST['building']); do not give a output.

Comment: You'll have to give us more details. Like put in log lines, and check where exactly is your code failing. Maybe then we can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use some Log and maybe sprintfs to figure out what is exactly going on. 
I#d start with the PHP. Try to open the URL from your browser and put some outputs in the PHP to see if everything works fine here. Post your results and you will probably get further help.

Comment: How have you submitted the Data in your Test? Have you send something with a from? Was the Form set to "POST"? Have you tried GET?

Comment: I've tried both POST and GET.
Do i miss something?

Thanks again.

Comment: Well try the easy way first: If you use GET, then you have to add the variables and values to the URL you call. So build the URL and call it from the browser. Post everything please: the code (if something changes), the url you call and the scripts output (if something changes)